# How can I make search with a substring of a word?

Tags: search

I would like to search with only part of a word,not the whole word.For example when I search name of people,I would like to search only the first 3 letters of the Last Name,not the whole name.Now if I put on  search only the first 3 letters I take no results.For the moment I am using the search api with apache  solr(and perhaps views).Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add ngramfilter to text type definition in schema.xml in solr config directory.

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="25" />
```

Comment: :I added it but its failing because there is no tokenizer..which class should I add for my tokenizer?